# create IBOutlet / IBAction & connect it with UI in a custom class

Tags: ios, swift2, ibaction, iboutlet

In my `ViewController`, I have two `UIImageView` which have IBOutlet connection to UI :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img2: UIImageView!
    ...
```

Now, I want to refactor my project to have a dedicated class `ImageManager` handles the images. So, the `ViewController` becomes like this :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var imgMgr: ImageManager!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imgMgr = ImageManager()
   }
}
```

I want the `ImageManager` class to declare the two `UIMageViews` the same way as that in `ViewController` and make the IBOutlet connection with UI, but looks like it doesn't work in this way:

```
class ImageManager : NSObject {
    @IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img2: UIImageView!
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to make a custom class holding the IBOutlet & IBAction which connects to interface builder UI components (instead of doing it in `ViewController`)?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are breaking the MVC pattern. You are creating a controller which is not an instance of `UIViewController` and that's when you start having problems. Do you want your manager to handle part of the screen? Then it should be a child view controller. Should just it handle data? Then it should be a model class and shouldn't own the image views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should do this. You should just manage your images in your custom UIImage class using for example:

```
//inside the function awakFromNib
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0 //will make all the images' corner radius of elements assigned to this custom class rounded
    self.clipsToBounds = true
```

Then you will drag the image outlets as usual to the view controller, but instead of setting its class to "UIImage", set it to the custom class name

```
@IBOutlet weak var someImg: CustomImgClass!
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make ImageManager subclass of UIView.
2. Create a new View under your ViewController and change it class name to ImageManager.
3. Drag Two UIImageViews to your ImageManager.
4. See the out Outlets of ImageManager View and connect them to the newly created View.
5. In your viewWillAppear just add the ImageManager as subview.